# call same primary key used on two foreign keys to display different rows/results

Tags: mysql, join, select

Users can be both senders and receivers of a letter (they send a letter, and can respond to a letter). As such, users are all stored in my tblMembers distinguished by mem_id_PK. However, I want to get out the usernames of the users as well.

My SQL below:

```
select tblLetters.letter_id_PK,
    tblLetters.letter_body,
    tblLetters.letter_createdDate,
    tblLetters.FK_member_id_writer AS 'Sender', 
    tblLetters.FK_member_id_adviser AS 'Receiver',
    tblMembers.mem_username AS 'Sender Name',
    tblMembers.mem_username AS 'Receiver Name'
from tblLetters
    inner join tblMembers on tblLetters.FK_member_id_writer = tblMembers.mem_id_PK
--  inner join tblMembers on tblLetters.FK_member_id_adviser = tblMembers.mem_id_PK
```

Returns:

```
letter_id_PK    letter_body         letter_createdDate      Sender  Receiver    Sender Name Receiver Name
1               Hello how are you?  2020-11-17 16:57:24.420 3       2           Sally       Sally
```

Expecting:

```
letter_id_PK    letter_body         letter_createdDate      Sender  Receiver    Sender Name Receiver Name
1               Hello how are you?  2020-11-17 16:57:24.420 3       2           Sally       John
```

My assumption is setting my FK's as mem_username but I haven't been able to do it distinctively as seen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use table name alias:

```
select tblLetters.letter_id_PK,
    tblLetters.letter_body,
    tblLetters.letter_createdDate,
    tblLetters.FK_member_id_writer AS 'Sender', 
    tblLetters.FK_member_id_adviser AS 'Receiver',
    sender.mem_username AS 'Sender Name',
    receiver.mem_username AS 'Receiver Name'
from tblLetters
    inner join tblMembers as sender on 
tblLetters.FK_member_id_writer = sender.mem_id_PK
 inner join tblMembers as receiver on 
tblLetters.FK_member_id_adviser = receiver.mem_id_PK
```